# Can an eternalist think that pastness and futureness are properties?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, time

I take an eternalist to be someone who believes there are no past/future things, it all exists "at once". I understand the position as it applies to concrete objects, but I am not so clear on what the position says about past/future events and properties of past-ness/futurity as such.

For instance, some eternalists appears to say that there is no absolute past event like "I slept at 10 yesterday." But there is a presently past event like "It *is* the case that I slept at 10 yesterday" (in fact, they even appeal to events like these to account for causations, which they take to be synchronic). But *what* makes it the case that "I slept at 10 yesterday" is false, whereas "it is the case that I slept at 10 yesterday" is true?

A similar worry applies to properties of pastness and futurity as well. On the one hand, an eternalist wants to say these properties are uninstantiated by concrete objects. On the other hand, they do not want to deny those properties as fictional themselves (thus, they are not like say "square circularity" or "magical"). But are they then admitting uninstantiated universals into their ontologies?

Comment: I am not sure this position is correct. I thought a presentist is the one who believes past stays in the past, future in the future and right now there is only now. The only meaning of past and future tenses is through present: my brain *has* an info that I slept at 10 yesterday.

Comment: If you are interested in these type questions, or doing research, you may want to add B. Croce to your reading list. Specifically,  his philosophy of history. The Wikipedia does not do him justice, but for what it's worth. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedetto_Croce

Comment: I changed "presentist" to "eternalist" everywhere, because the question does not make sense otherwise. On the usual reading eternalists think that pastness and futuness are indeed "fictions", or rather subjective illusions, of "living through" the time. Objectively speaking, it is all there at once. Of course, they still need to account for time passage by other means, which is why many think that the eternalism/presentism debate is purely verbal with no substance, see [Lombard's Time for a Change](http://archive.clas.wayne.edu/Multimedia/Philosophy/files/LBL%20Time%20for%20a%20Change.pdf).

Comment: @Conifold Well, if one believes there is some kind of universal archives where everything that happens is stored and some kind of universe maintainer that can open them at any moment, it is more than a purely verbal dispute. But I'm sure there are not many advocates of this or similar views.

Comment: @Conifold sorry but I did mean presentist rather than eternalist. I think what you mean by eternalist is what I take to be the B-theorist (one who believes there is no passage of time). Of course most if not all B-theorists are eternalists. But the presentism/eternalism debate is an ontological dispute of what there is, whereas the A-theroy/B-theory debate is a metaphysical one regarding the nature of time. That is why an A-theorist can also be an eternalist (e.g. the moving spotlight view). And I am puzzled by whether a presentist who does not believe in *the existence* of past/future objects

Comment: @Conifold can nevertheless think *the existence* of properties of past-ness and future-ness.

Comment: I am not sure you understand completely what presentism means. Take a chess board for example. Imagine a particular configuration. Now, say, you have to decide what was previous configuration. For a presentist there is no answer, no clue. For an eternalist (or growing block theorist) there is one, there is some kind of metaphysical object that gives a clue. Although, as a presentist you still know that in previous configuration no king could be more than 2 pieces far.

Comment: @rus9384 perhaps I am missing something but I am not seeing how this is inconsistent with my characterization of presentism. I was referring to moving spot-light theorist (one who thinks there is a block universe with a moving spotlight, cf. SEP article on Time Travel) as an *eternalist* and an A-theorist. A growing block theorist might be someone taking an intermediate position between presentism and eternalism (since there is an asymmetry between the ontology of future and past objects). A hardcore eternalist would think future objects are every bit as real as past objects.

Comment: Seems apt: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/716781-time-present-and-time-past-are-both-perhaps-present-in

Comment: I think you should probably ask a new question, and try to phrase it in terms that [SEP uses](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#PreEteGroUniThe). what you explained does not come through in this post. Even those who deny existence of past/future then introduce tensed verbs as in "exist*ed*" anyway, and can then attach properties in those terms. Which is one more reason to think that the debate is vacuous.